# How to create an additional summary row within an excel sheet with alasql

Tags: excel, alasql

I'm creating an excel sheet with alasql. For example my sheet looks like

```
date       | value1 | value2
---------- | ------ | ------
2016-01-01 | 2      | 3
2016-01-02 | 1      | 4
```

Is it possible to add a summary row at the bottom of the values? E.g.

```
date       | value1 | value2
---------- | ------ | ------
2016-01-01 | 2      | 3
2016-01-02 | 1      | 4

Sum        | 3      | 7
```

Comment: No - it is not possible to add a sum at the end directly from AlaSQL. 

You could make the sum in a different sheet - if that is woth anything. 

Or you could make data with AlaSQL and use https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs to make the excel as you want

Comment: @mathiasrw how that can be achieved in exceljs?